# Ubuntu installer partition maker is disabled!

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop along with win 10. I want to have dual boot. I shrank my c drive and have some unallocated space now. I'm using SSD drive in my laptop. After booting laptop to live environment I choose to install Ubuntu. It doesn't show me install along Windows option. Thus, I choose OTHER from menu and try to install manually. First I need to make positions from the unallocated space. When I select the unallocated space the + button for creating partition is disabled!!! Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Did you remember to disable Windows Fast Boot, and then completely shut down windows? That's an important step.

Comment: Thank you. I disabled fast boot and the issue was resolved. However, the installed Ubuntu is super super SLOW!!! It is on a Western Digital SSD drive and should be fast!!!

Comment: Different issue. Close this question and open a new question. Use the Search box to see similar questions asked before, and the information you will need to provide.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.